# Help identifying the features of this QQ-plot

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, normality-assumption, qq-plot

I am wondering how to go about answering this question. I understand that the second option regarding the p-value is correct, as this graph shows non-normally distributed data - and the p-value states that the chance that the data shown is actually from a normally distributed sample is less than 0.005%

For the first option regarding sample size, the issue is that this would be correct if the question said "not reasonable". With more samples, we get a better idea about the distribution of the actual population. Here the data appears non-normal.

The third option is confusing me as I am not sure if "pattern" is referring to linearity or a pattern in general. The assumption of normality as stated is not reasonable, and personally I do not believe this data follows a pattern especially on the high end.

The fourth option I believe is incorrect, as a single outlier should not be a determinant for whether a distribution is normal or not - if it were the high end with its multiple odd values I would say otherwise.

The fifth option seems irrelevant, as the data points being close together does not reflect normality, but rather the pattern of the points themselves.

[image]

Comment: Is this for a class? If so, please add the self-study tag, and read its wiki. It would help if you posted your thoughts on each of those points, why you think they could be right or could be wrong (all the better if you can argue both ways).

Comment: Hi Dave, I went and added some extra details to the post including my thoughts on each option. I also added the appropriate tag.

Comment: "less than 0.005%" might just be true, but what the output shows you is just P-value "less than 0.005". You have no licence for converting probabilities between 0 and 1 to percents. Without any context this is a very poor question and even with the context added it would be a poor question. Are you allowed to choose more than one option?

Comment: The question allows for multiple selections.